# Moving element from one array to another, using the same Mongo UpdateOne query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data model:

```
"finances" : {
    "futurePostings" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "test",
            "orderId" : ObjectId("614702b9e98e83bc5d7d3d62")
        }
    ],
    "balance" : []
}
```

Then, I'm trying to move the element inside `futurePosting` to `balance`. I could remove it from futurePostings, but I can't figure out if would be possible to use the positional $ operator (or any other command) to push this same document inside balance, via the same query.

```
   db.collection.updateOne(
        {
          "finances.futurePostings.orderId": ObjectId(orderId),
        },
        {
          $push: { "finances.balance": ?? },
          $pull: {
            "finances.futurePostings": { orderId: ObjectId(orderId) },
          },
        }
      );
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in a regular update query, but you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- pull from `futurePostings`

  - `$filter` to iterate loop of `futurePostings` array and check not equal to condition to remove provided `orderId`
- push into `balance`

  - `$filter` to iterate loop of `futurePostings` array and check equal to condition and filter matching `orderId` element
  - `$concatArrays` to concat current `balance` array and new element from above filtered result

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "finances.futurePostings.orderId": ObjectId(orderId) },
  [{
    $set: {
      "finances.futurePostings": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$finances.futurePostings",
          cond: {
            $ne: ["$$this.orderId", ObjectId(orderId)]
          }
        }
      },
      "finances.balance": {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$finances.balance",
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$finances.futurePostings",
              cond: {
                $eq: ["$$this.orderId", ObjectId(orderId)]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AKIc2PeG_U6)